# I leave a question regarding DRF multi-image processing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = "image"

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            "id",
            "author",
            "content",
            "images",
        )
```

I'd like to get the results the following response from the above communication codes.
(위 코드로 GET 통신에서 아래와 같은 응답 결과를 얻고 싶은데요.)

```
{
  "id": 53,
  "author": 1,
  "post": "awesome",
  "images": {
     "image": "abc.png",
     "image": "def.jpg",
  }
}
```

The images field does not apply and appears like below.
(images 필드가 적용되지 않고 아래와 같이 나오는 상황입니다.)

```
{
  "id": 53,
  "author": 1,
  "post": "awesome",
}
```

Which part should I fix? I also attach the code for the model.
(어떤 부분을 고쳐야할까요? 모델 단 코드도 같이 첨부합니다.)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = ForeignKey("Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image", blank=True)
```

Comment: You can not have ***same `Key`s multiple times in a JSON Object (or Python dict)***

Comment: Arakkal Abu //
like image Key? So what can I do?

Comment: It should be a list rather than dict

Comment: Arakkal Abu // But I can't read even one image, is there another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit models.py
(models.py를 수정하시면 됩니다.)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = ForeignKey("Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image", blank=True)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why this is.
If you know, please leave a comment.